# How do I remove my Campagnolo Veloce rear brake caliper?

Tags: brakes

I'm trying to remove my rear brake caliper to put a fender/mudguard clamp on. I've removed the rear nut and I assume the brake should then slide straight out. But it won't. It is definitely a little loose, it will rotate freely and has maybe 1mm of play, but even putting a reasonable amount of force on it, it will not slide out of the hole in the rear frame.

What am I missing? I assume I don't need to unscrew the caliper out of the frame.

Edit: Sorry about my woeful care of this question. I meant to put up some photos and explain in more detail, but didn't get around to it :(

In the end I unscrewed the "rear" nut (closest to the front of the bike) a little and tapped it lightly with a wrench and the caliper did come out. Turns out it was just a very tight fit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you've removed the nut, you could try to insert a punch through the mounting hole, and gently tap it a few times to try and free it. I reckon there's dirt, mud, and perhaps rust in there that's causing it to stick. A picture would be useful if something else is amiss, but it's hard to imagine anything else.

Comment: I've got wishbone style chainstays. So there's a hole for the brake caliper to go through, but not a 'traditional' bridge.

Comment: Ahhh OK. Edited.

Comment: Another case for good old WD-40 !

Comment: @Carel Yes, this is a job for a penetrating oil! One of the very few times when I'd let WD40 anywhere near a bike...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're exactly wrong, unfortunately. The caliper is held in place by the nut at the front - on the opposite side of the brake bridge to the bulk of the caliper. What you've removed is the nut that holds the whole assembly together (or at least one of the nuts).

[image]

The nut you want to undo is at the top of this image, the one that attaches the brake to the frame. Note that it's recessed so you will probably have to slide the brake out of the frame and attach the fender to the brake side of the frame rather than the nut side.

Comment: I don't think so... I'm referring to front and back of the caliper, rather than the bike. Sorry, I see that's confusing. I'm reaching in through the frame (I don't have a bridge) and undoing that nut that's sticking out on the top of the diagram you included.

Comment: And the caliper doesn't slide out of the frame when you do that? This is another case where a picture would be very useful.